Developer Name for Survey
UPDATE - thanks everyone - I've gotten a little further and was able to get the Survey developer name.  Now I'm trying to get the Survey Question developer name and I must not be using the correct info, would someone take a look and see where I need to change?
SELECT Name, DeveloperName FROM SurveyQuestion
WHERE Name = 'My Customer Success Manager CSM reviewed my plan features and answered my 401k questions.'
I am very new to SQL in Salesforce.  I've been tasked with getting the Developer Name for a Survey.  When I try, I get the error that Survey is not supported.  Can anyone give me a better way to request this?

I'm not familiar with Surveys, but it sounds like a feature enablement issue or Permission Set License assignment issue.  Have you enabled trhe feature that uses Surveys and assigned anay necessary permission set licenses / permission sets?

Adding a link for Surveys documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.enable_surveys.htm&type=5

When you get a "sObject type X is not supported" while making a SOQL call, but you know the object exists, it typically means you do not have Read access to the object. This may be due to your profile missing the Read X permission on your profile, or the feature is not enabled in the organization. In your case, make sure that you have enabled surveys and that your profile has the appropriate permissions to access them.
